# Can't connect to apache from an external IP

Tags: apache, apache2, ip, port, netstat

I used to have a web server running on my Raspberry Pi and plugged it back in but for some reason it is not working with an external IP anymore. The local IP works fine.

1. I've used whatsmyip.org to find my external IP.
2. Port 80 is forwarded to my Raspi's IP.
3. Used netstat -anp | grep apache and it listens to the port 80

This is about as far as I've gotten trying to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this could be the problem.

every time you connect your raspberry to a wireless router its ip address changes.

You need to reserve the ip address of your pi.

http://www.coolwebhome.co.uk/sagem/sagem-reserve.jpg

Comment: +1 That wasn't the actual way to solve it but it made me realize what was wrong. For some reason when I unplug the power from my Raspi, I need to delete the port forwarding rules and re-apply them even though the IP's haven't changed.